# GCM Android 6.0 Not work

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, push

Android 6.0 push messages not received.

I use guide https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client ,
all working on 5.0 and 4.4.2, but 6.0 not receive any messages.

Comment: Problem is solved. I received notification seldom with little delay.

Comment: How you solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test with the [demo app](https://github.com/google/gcm/tree/master/samples/android). You may want to enable logging (the "eye" icon on the action bar). The logs will help trace the issue (refer to the HTTP response from the GCM server).

Using a Nexus 5 running 6.0, I managed to register and receive messages successfully.